# how to detect main server ip address from client system using java?

Tags: java, ip

Is it possible to get main server system's(which is connected to LAN) ip address from client system using java?

If yes, how can i do using code?

Comment: If your client is connected to the server, it must be aware of the IP no ?

Comment: @ortis, no, your client is connected to server via its external IP address that can be the address of load ballancer. However OP wants to detect the internal IP of concrete server as it is defined in LAN.

Comment: @AlexR ok fine.but is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is impossible whether using java or any other programming language. This is the reason that LANs exist. The internal IP address is not sent outside the local network and therefore cannot be detected.

However if client and server are developed especially to complete this task to can send the IP on application level. For example to send the IP as a HTTP header if connection is done over HTTP.

Comment: ok i understand but i must do this one. so is there any other solution?